# While writing a code for thread synchronization in java i cam across the following error

Tags: java

So I am a beginner in java.

Yesterday while writing a code for thread synchronization I came across an error `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. Code and the error are specified below. Here the shared variable among threads is `a`. From what I can guess from the error the variable `b` is having problems in taking the second value.

```
        class Sum
        {
            synchronized void addition(int a)
            {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("enter vale of b: ");
                int b = sc.nextInt();
                sc.close();
                int c = a + b;
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
        class ThreadP1 extends Thread
        {
            Sum s1;
            ThreadP1(Sum s1)
            {
                this.s1 = s1;
            }
            public void run()
            {
                Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("enter element a: ");
                s1.addition(sc1.nextInt());
                sc1.close();
            }
        }
        class ThreadP2 extends Thread
        {
            Sum s1;
            ThreadP2(Sum s1)
            {
                this.s1 = s1;
            }
            public void run()
            {
                Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("enter element a: ");
                s1.addition(sc2.nextInt());
                sc2.close();
            }
        }
    
    
    
        public class Synchronisation1 
        {
            public static void main(String args[])
            {
                Sum obj3 = new Sum();
                ThreadP1 t12 = new ThreadP1(obj3);
                t12.start();
                ThreadP2 t13 = new ThreadP2(obj3);
                t13.start();
            }
        }
```

### Error

```
>Thread-1 java.util.NoSuchElementException  
        >>at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        >>at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)   
        >>at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        >>at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        >>at Sum.addition(Synchronisation1.java:8)
        >>at ThreadP2.run(Synchronisation1.java:40)
```

Comment: You have closed a Scanner built on System.in. Closing the scanner closes System.in, and it cannot be reopened. Solution, do not close the scanner until the program ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, by closing the `Scanner`, you close the `System.in`.
The latter scanner will get an exception when it realizes `System.in` is closed.

One way to fix it will be not to close the scanner.

By the way, `ThreadP1`, `ThreadP2` seem to do the same thing. Consider creating 2 instances of the same class instead.